# How to make pdnsd just use one probed server not to flood with server uptests?

Tags: linux, dns

Why pdnsd responds slowly/fails many requests to it even if it has found working upstream server?

I want pdnsd to just use the DNS server {it has probed,that is proven} to work and search for other configured variants only if that chosen server fails.

/* Most time only about 1-2 of configured servers does work, each time different ones. */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure it properly:

```
    caching=on;
    proxy_only=on;
    lean_query=on;
    purge_cache=off;
```